# What was the purpose of pausing on this photo in the Legend of Korra?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

At the end of Beginnings- Part 2, we see Korra riding on a flying bison past a peculiar looking island which kind of reminds me of a Lion Turtle for some strange reason, but what was the purpose behind pausing on it?

Is there some hidden meaning behind it and was it refering to Lion Turtles. That bit's just speculation on my part though.

[image: Island]

Comment: Pure speculation, but I'd guess it's a subconscious part of Korra noticing the similarity between the island and a Lion Turtle. This makes sense with the Lion Turtles showing up again later in the season.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose behind of pausing this scene in the episode of Legend of Korra: Beginnings, Part 2, was to refer to the Lion Turtle. According to Beginnings, Part 1, we see the first Avatar who is Wan. This episode shows us how the Avatar is able to bend all four elements through the Lion Turtles. To me, this was significant that a Lion Turtle is near Korra after she has learned about the first Avatar.

My source is just watching Beginnings Part 1 and 2.
[image: Avatar Wan receiving fire bending from a fire lion turtle.]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was just a Easter egg. They were just showing Korra flying past a lion turtle because it had just been relevant and we also know that there’s only one left on Earth. The one that taught Aang energybending. I didn’t even catch it until my third time watching the series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This does seem reasonable, but can you provide any stronger evidence?  For example, anything one of the creators might have said.